# How to choose between member and non-member functions?

Tags: c++

[Effective C++](http://books.google.com/books?id=Qx5oyB49poYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=effective%20C%2b%2b&hl=en&sa=X&ei=F8cYUsKqJIrWiwLdn4GwCg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=effective%20C%2b%2b&f=false) says to "Prefer non-member non-frend functions to member functions" (item 23). The rationale makes sense to me: it minimizes the API "surface area". But in practice, I often find it hard to convince people (including myself) to follow. For example, suppose I have some shape classes, and they are supposed to support perimeter and area calculations:

```
// @interface
class Shape {
 public:
  virtual double Area() = 0;
  virtual double Perimeter() = 0;
}

class Rectangle : public Shape {
 public:
  Rectangle(double width, double height);

  double width();
  double height();

  ...
};

class Circle : public Shape {
 public:
  Circle(double radius);

  double radius();
  ...
};
```

According to this advice, it seems that Area and Perimeter should be non-member non-friend functions (not methods), because they can be. E.g. area of a Rectangle can be calculated from the width and height methods like so:

```
double Area(const Rectangle& rectangle) {
  return rectangle.width() * rectangle.height();
}
```

In fact, neither Rectangle nor Circle have any internal state that isn't exposed by their getters, and it's hard to imagine how that would ever be the case. Therefore, any function that operates on these should not be a method. Another example:

```
// The diameter of a shape is the (circle) diameter of the smallest circle
// that contains a shape.
double Diameter(const Rectangle& rectangle) {
  double w = rectangle.width();
  double h = rectangle.height();
  return sqrt(w * w + h * h);
}
```

Am I missing something here? Or is this actually bad advice??

Comment: That is *precisely* what Scott is suggesting. The function to calculate area can be de-coupled from the shape classes themselves.

Comment: If you model data, instead of behavior (which is good, I think) you can get rid of the virtual member functions by non-member functions.

Comment: Thanks guys. One problem I see with this approach is that I lose polymorphism. E.g. if I have a container of shape pointers, then it is not possible for me to compute the area of all of the elements (without casting). This seems to be why all the OO books recommend virtual methods.

Comment: allyourcode: you could use template specialization.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I do not see how templates help.

template<Shape>
double Area(Shape *shape) { return -1; }

// specialize... //

for (Shape *shape : shapes) {
  Area<???>(shape);  // Type must be known at compile time, no? //
}

With virtual Area(), the statement in the for loop becomes

shape->Area();

which is exactly what the OO people intended.

Comment: Plus, you now have this template that can be applied to ANY type, even though you only want it to apply to shapes!

Comment: allyourcode: what you miss is simply the fact C++ is not an OOP language, but multi-paradigm. The second post is of course incorrect as well because you can restrict templates to certain features of course. Seems, you have not studied the template programming much, just the OOP part of C++. Not an offense, just saying.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I think, templates are definitely the wrong road to go down on this. It will lead to a completely rigid design, in which the compiler has to be able to deduce the precise type of each object at any point, loosing entirely the flexibility that made OOP big. I guess, you have never worked with ObjectiveC, and if I'm right with that assumption, you should try it out; it's object orientation at its best, fostering really flexible designs. You can't do that with templates.

Comment: cmaster: are you saying eigen is completely wrong then? Have you seen benchmarks between virtual stuff and things like eigen? There are order of magnitudes in performance. You seem to be an OOP purist even though C++ is not an OOP language, but multi-paradigm. :)

Comment: It is a good question. I thought about this recently. E.g. the Qt api does not try to decouple functions. Non-member functions are rare in their api.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to calculate the area of polymorphic `Shape` objects, then Scott's advice is not for your case.  Because you cannot calculate the area with an external function, because in fact you don't have public access to the information that is required.  Namely, whether the object is actually a circle, a rectangle, or something else.  So this is a job for virtual functions.

In fact, in Scott's psuedo-code algorithm for determining the correct placement of a function (taken from [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197), as I do not have the book), the first test is this:

```
if (f needs to be virtual)
    make f a member function of C;
```

Comment: Except friends. That would be a valid way in my opinion, especially when virtual methods are getting slow for rendering.

Comment: Doesn't this argument apply to his WebBrowser example? Let's say I have Chrome and Firefox subclasses. It might not be true that clearEverything can be implemented the same way as a non-member function. E.g. maybe one browser supports storing passwords, while the other does not.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The advice specifically excludes friends, because they have just as much access to privates as member functions.

Comment: No, I was referring to your accessibility. Friend is one and valid way to solve in certain "operator" scenarios, and actually they are even not the only way. ;)

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  Friends would be a valid way of what?

Comment: To access private members. Besides, there is no private data here as the author explicitly wrote. Also, it would be very simple to expose a type method which actually Qt is even doing in Qt3D, so I think your answer is a bit off in that sense. IMO, Scott's suggestion is just fine here, too, but it is up to the voters to judge. ;-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Still lost.  Who said anything about accessing private members?

Comment: "Because you cannot calculate the area with an external function, because in fact you don't have public access to the information that is required. Namely, whether the object is actually a circle, a rectangle, or something else. So this is a job for virtual functions." -> This is unreasonable in this scenario in my opinion.

Comment: @allyourcode: What WebBrowser example?  Is that in his book?  I'm afraid I don't have that.  I do have this though: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197 -- and in his pseudo-code algorithm, the first test is *"if (f needs to be virtual) make f a member function of C"*

Comment: @Benjamin: where was the type mentioned in the original question? In fact, I see that there is no private or unaccessible data.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have if you have a class with some variables that are directly accessible via getters and setters? Right, nothing more or less than a `struct` with an "object oriented" facade. There is absolutely nothing object oriented around the usage of such a *data* container.

The whole point about object orientation, as I percieve it, is to model *behaviour*, not *data*. In this respect, an abstract shape class with pure virtual methods to calculate area and perimeter is a perfectly valid design: It abstracts from the data and exposes the behaviour that you need. If I were you, I would think twice about adding the getters for the fundamental parameters (no useful abstraction), and thrice about adding the respective setters (breaks encapsulation).

But, by all means, do not be religious about either having accessors, or not having them, or avoiding simple plain old data structures, or even about an object oriented design. All of this has it's uses, and avoiding it for the sake of avoiding it will lead to a poor design in one case or another. All I'm saying is: Think about what best suits your needs, and then do it entirely indifferent to what religious rules some big programmers have come up with.

Comment: All this has been already mentioned by the two other answers. ;-)

Comment: Yes, Benjamin's answer is in the same direction. But I believe that there is something in my answer that is not found in Benjamins, no? However, if you feel, that my answer is just a duplicate, feel free to vote me down...

Comment: I do not vote down people's answer so easily. Do not be concerned about it.